# GitHub Actions - set up

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to set up GitHub actions for a ROR project and not sure how to set up the postgres so it is **not** running in a container as a service. I need to be running this on the vm , not as a service in docker. Tech policy says no to containers and docker.

has anyone got this done who can provide assistance or yaml?

Comment: You could eventually run a script in a step to set up Postgres on the VM according to the runner, then execute the operations you want to perform. Is that an option?

Comment: that would be an option. tell me that's not difficult for a complete noob with no knowledge of db's lol

Comment: There might be some actions on the [github markeplace](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&query=&type=actions&verification=), as well as shell or bash scripts on the internet you could use in your workflow according to your context. A little research is worth it as others may have need the same thing before you  (I won't be able to help now, but I'll give it a look this week-end if possible).